# Why is Core Plot giving errors about doxygen after upgrading to Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, core-plot

After installing Xcode 4 and attempting to build using Core Plot, I'm seeing the following errors:

> error: Cannot open file
>   /Users/Kawapoo/CorePlot/Source/framework/../documentation/doxygen
>   touch.config for writing
>
> error: configuration file
>   /Users/Kawapoo/CorePlot/Source/framework/../documentation/doxygen
>   touch.config not found!

This was building fine under Xcode 3.x.  What could be wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a case-sensitive file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i again install coreplot in my project and its working now.